# enable CORS setting for soap web service on visual studio development server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web, cors

i am trying to add CORS setting by enabling "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in Web Service method shown below. However, I'm still getting error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' Am i missing anything?

```
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        [WebMethod]
        public ClientData[] GetClientData(int Number)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:52630");

            ClientData[] Clients = null;

            if (Number > 0 && Number <= 10)
            {
                Clients = new ClientData[Number];
                for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
                {
                    Clients[i].Name = "Client " + i.ToString();
                    Clients[i].ID = i;
                }
            }

            return Clients;
        }
```

Comment: Chrome does not support localhost for CORS, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Comment: @Shiraz: so far it only works in IE, doesn't work in Mozilla or chrome either.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your web.config

You can adjust if needed. This example I only open for .aspx

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
      </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You may need something like this too.

```
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: @PoloHoleSet On your handler. The basic idea is that, we need to intercept the option preflight and reply with appropriate headers.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but sometimes my assumptions lead me astray.  Thanks for circling back so long after answering.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
           value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"
           value="true" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
           value="SOAPAction, Content-Type,Authorization" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
           value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

for details check https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/827596/Cross-domain-SOAP-call-with-XmlHttpRequest-to-a-we